# Laravel Model Bind with repository and Mockery fails

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mockery

I am trying to test my service with `Mockery`. I have bound the route param `{user}` to my service:

```
$repo = 'Services\\UserService';
$router->bind('user', function($id, $route) use($repo) {
    return $this->app->make($repo)->get($id);
});
```

When I run my first test it succeeds.

```
$mocked = Mockery::mock('UserService');
\App::instance('UserService', $mocked);

$mocked->shouldReceive('create')
       ->once()
       ->andReturn($user);
```

When my next test runs it fails

```
$mocked = Mockery::mock('UserService');
\App::instance('UserService', $mocked);

$mocked->shouldReceive('update')
       ->once()
       ->andReturn('1');
```

Dumping out in the `router->bind` method

```
dump(get_class($this->app->make($repo));
```

I get `Services\UserService` the first time but the second time I get `Mockery_0_Services_UserService` and then this error:

```
testing.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 
'Method Mockery_0_Services_UserService::get() does not exist on this mock object
```

I would assume that it has something to do with the `App::instance` method but I am not sure.

What could be the issue here?